# Time signatures in timetk package

Tags: r, time-series, timetk

I'm working with time series data and I'm curious what does `week2`, `week3` and `week4` refer to when using `tk_augment_timeseries_signature`

I'm working with the weekly data (`walmart_sales_weekly`) from the `timetk` package:

```
data_tbl <- timetk::walmart_sales_weekly %>%
  select(id, Date, Weekly_Sales) %>%
  mutate(id = as.factor(id)) %>% 
  set_names(c("id", "date", "value")) %>% 
  filter(id == "1_95") %>%
  mutate(value = log1p(x = value)) %>%
  mutate(value = standardize_vec(value)) %>%
  tk_augment_timeseries_signature(.date_var = date) %>%
  select(-diff, -matches("(.xts$)|(.iso$)|(hour)|(minute)|(second)|(am.pm)|(wday)|(day)|(mweek)"))
```

The help documentation i.e. `?tk_augment_timeseries_signature` makes no reference to these features

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [vignette](https://github.com/business-science/timetk/blob/886c496c030fe942af27c6e68abe4dc750b36e70/vignettes/TK01_Working_With_Time_Series_Index.Rmd) in their github page, they are referring to the different frequency based upon the `week` time feature (`week2` for bi-weekly frequency, `week3` for tri-weekly frequency). They are created through the use of `modulus`.

Comment: Thanks John, I changed the original question to specify the help docs, good find on the github page. Unfortunately for me I am still not following, the frequency and modulus logic. The date '2010-02-12' have 1,1 & 3 populated for week2, 3 & 4 respectively, can you share how these figures are calculated? Thanks